# Xcode 5.1, swap position of several UILabels

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm using Xcode 5.1 and I have several UILabels that I need to swap positions.  I have Auto Layout turned off.  I need these labels to swap position during a swipe gesture.  I'm already swapping the position of two UIContainer objects, you'll see that in the code, and I need the labels to travel along with the container.  Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
//Get the center of each view container
CGPoint targetHomeCenter = _vistingTeamContainer.center;
CGPoint targetVisitorCenter = _homeTeamContainer.center;
CGPoint targetHomeNameCenter = _visitingTeamName.center;
CGPoint targetVisitorNameCenter = _homeTeamName.center;
//Get the center of each past score label
CGPoint targetHomeGame1 = self.visitGame1.center;
CGPoint targetHomeGame2 = self.visitGame2.center;
CGPoint targetHomeGame3 = self.visitGame3.center;
CGPoint targetVisitGame1 = self.homeGame1.center;
CGPoint targetVisitGame2 = self.homeGame2.center;
CGPoint targetVisitGame3 = self.homeGame3.center;


//Create the animation and swap positions of the controllers
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                      delay:0.0f
     usingSpringWithDamping:0.7f
      initialSpringVelocity:0.5f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^(){
                     //Move the containers
                     _homeTeamContainer.center = targetHomeCenter;
                     _homeTeamName.center = targetHomeNameCenter;
                     _vistingTeamContainer.center = targetVisitorCenter;
                     _visitingTeamName.center = targetVisitorNameCenter;

                     //Now move the past scores
                     self.homeGame1.center = targetVisitGame1;
                     self.homeGame2.center = targetVisitGame2;
                     self.homeGame3.center = targetVisitGame3;
                     self.visitGame1.center = targetHomeGame1;
                     self.visitGame2.center = targetHomeGame2;
                     self.visitGame3.center = targetHomeGame3;

                 }
                 completion:NULL];
};
```

The UIContainers move just fine, as expected.  The UILabels don't move at all.

I have also tried `CGPoint targetHomeGame1 = _visitGame1.center` but that doesn't do anything either.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGPoint targetVisitGame1 = _homeGame1.center;
self.homeGame1.center = targetVisitGame1;
```

Why would this want to move? There is no change in point's coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, Earl, I don't understand your question.  I just want to animate the swap of the uilabels.  I was just showing what I tried to do and was not successful at.

Comment: I am not asking anything, it's rhetorical. It will not move because the start and end coordinates are the same. 
Cant' you see that from the copied code?

Comment: OMG!  I can't believe I did that!  Thanks for pointing that out.  I'll give you an up vote for that and I really want to delete this because it makes me look really bad!  I marked your answer as the answer but can't upvote you because I'm still new on the site.